# Android Drawing app crashing

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android programming and started out with a simple drawing app. I found and collated some code after much browsing but the code doesn't seem to work. The app opens having a white screen but doesn't do anything when I touch and drag. No lines or anything to be seen. Just the white screen.

Here is the code.

```
package com.drawing.emeraldsoul.drawingapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

class MyView extends View {
// setup initial color
private final int paintColor = Color.BLACK;
// defines paint and canvas
private Paint drawPaint;

private Path path = new Path();

public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    setupPaint();
}

// Setup paint with color and stroke styles
private void setupPaint() {
    drawPaint = new Paint();
    drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
    drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawPath(path, drawPaint);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float pointX = event.getX();
    float pointY = event.getY();
    // Checks for the event that occurs
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            path.moveTo(pointX, pointY);
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            path.lineTo(pointX, pointY);
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    // Force a view to draw again
    postInvalidate();
    return true;
}
}

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public MainActivity() {
        super();
    }
}
```

The main file is MainActivity and hence, I added the public class with an empty constructor. If I try adding the whole paint code in the MainActivity class extending from View, then the app crashes, doesn't even start, with an error saying "no empty constructor found". So I coded this way. I am not sure if this is right.

Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong?

Thanks a lot, in advance,
Esash

Comment: Well this MyView class is great and all but how do you expect the MainActivity to know about it? You say you didn't include it anywhere in it. It just coexists in the same universe. Maybe even on the same pc. But that doesn't make it work :)

Comment: Please read over [Creating Custom Views](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

> the app crashes, doesn't even start, with an error saying "no empty constructor found".

I think that wants an empty constructor for the View class.

```
public MyView() { 
    // TODO: Maybe place something here?
}

public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    setupPaint();
}
```

But the real problem probably lies in that you have no `onCreate` for your Activity. And that does not need the empty constructor anyways.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.YourLayoutWithMyView); // TODO: Put your layout here
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in you include your `MyView` in your app's layout file that is being rendered.

After an instance of `MyView` is included in your layout file, you can go to `Settings > Developer options` on your testing device and enable `Show layout bounds` and `Show touches` for more debugging with this particular app.